# Jquery datepicker change dateFormat to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the Jquery datepicker to add the selected dates to an SQL database in time format using `dateFormat : '@'`.

However, this uses js milliseconds and I need it in UNIX timestamp format which is in seconds. So basically I get an extra 3 zeros on the end.

I know I can /1000 to get the correct integer, but how do I do that in the js before it is entered into the db?

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.MyDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : '@'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer for anyone else who has the same issue. Instead of using timestamps, I stuck to standard date formats. However, you need to check the different date formats between jquery and php. For example, the date 03-01-16 in jquery will be 'dd-mm-yy' while in php, the same date format would be 'd-m-Y'.

Answer (score 0):

try the below, it has temp value for your SQL DB.

```
var tempSQLvalue;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.MyDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat : '@',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            tempSQLvalue = date.slice(0,date.length-3);
            console.log(tempSQLvalue);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry vtz, that didn't work. Still get the same integer added

Comment: well yes you need to add tempSQLvalue instead of the val of the input, you should be able to see the changed value in the console log